# Foreach loop to insert multiple row depends on date with a trigger CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, triggers, codeigniter-3

I have a range of dates that I wish to add a row in my table foreach selected day of the week, so I needed a trigger to do that because this must be done after an insert on another table, and I'm facing some errors, so here is my code hoping that you can tell me what I have done wrong!

```
$begin = $this->input->post('debut_semestre');
$end = $this->input->post('fin_semestre');
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
$array_jour = array();
$interval = new DateInterval('P7D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
foreach ($daterange as $key ) {
    $array_jour[] = $key->format("Y-m-d");
}
                    

$this->db->query("create or replace trigger 'insert_seance'
    after insert on 'emploi'
    foreach row begin".

    foreach ($array_jour as $key) {."
            
        INSERT INTO seance(id, Date, jour, id_salle, id_groupe, id_ens, id_mat, de, a, etat, id_semestre) VALUES (null,".$key.",".$jour.",".$id_salle.",".$id_groupe.",".$id_ens.",".$id_mat.",".$date_debut.",".$date_fin."'active',".$id_semestre." )
        ".}."
)";
```

Comment: Why do you even want this as a trigger in your db? You should try and avoid mixing business logic between the db and your php backend. There are event libraries available for codeigniter which will allow you to handle your issue in a better way.

Comment: can you please tell me the names of these libraries or something that I can do some research with  ?

Comment: I can't find any event word in codeigniter documentation! help me please

Comment: It's not good to just post an answer and go like that knowing that your post is not usefull

Comment: First, not everyone lives in the same timezone or is able to help you when you wish. Secondly, you could have googled for event libraries for the framework and find something like https://github.com/nathanmac/CodeIgniter-Events yourself in less than a minute.

Comment: I found that and it's not what I want

Comment: You posted a `PHP DateTime object` via the request? `$end = $this->input->post('fin_semestre');
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );`